# cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE doesn't work on my windows, still looking for MS compiler

Tags: c++, select, cmake, compilation, clang

I've got MSVS 2022 and clang llvm installed on win10, I'm using vscode and cmake(version 3.23.2). On powershell command line I have a directory containing several cpp files and a CMakeLists.txt, then:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="..\cmaketoolchain.win10clang" ..
```

The content of cmaketoolchain.win10clang is as below:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")

SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER             "d:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang.exe")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS                "-Wall -std=c99")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG          "-g")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     "-Os -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE        "-O4 -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")

SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER             "d:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin\\clang++.exe")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS                "-Wall")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG          "-g")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL     "-Os -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE        "-O4 -DNDEBUG")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "-O2 -g")
```

Well, on running cmake it still prints:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="..\cmaketoolchain.win10clang" ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.31104.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.31104.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: d:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
...
```

And generate a bunch of vcproj files.

Did I miss anything about cmake or environmental setting? How to solve it?

Comment: What happens if you explicitely set a generator that differs from the default one on the Windows platform, e.g. add `-G "Ninja"` to the CMake command line? Be sure to clear the build directory before rerunning CMake.

Comment: @vre This helped me solve the same problem, but I had to set CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM in my toolchain file to point at my ninja.exe. After that it stops trying to use Visual Studio.